# Is snprintf or vsnprintf better, and how can I ensure I'm using them securely?

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow

I decided to run a static analysis tool on some old code and I found a bunch of places where I'm using sprintf. The tool recommends replacing the calls with either vsnprintf or snprintf because sprintf doesn't do any sort of bounds checking for buffer overflows.

I can easily just do a find and replace on the calls so that it uses snprintf or vsnprintf instead, but I want to make sure there's nothing else that needs to be done in order to make the functionality safe

In some cases the strings being used originate in user input, and in some cases they do not.

Does anybody have any advice on how to do it right?

Comment: "Is snprintf or vsnprintf better" It depends on whether you have variadic arguments or a `va_list`.

Comment: Not worried about portability, no.

Comment: It should be noted that C11 introduces the (even) safer `sprintf_s`, `snprintf_s`, `vsnprintf_s`. They're optional, however.

Answer (score 8):

> I can easily just do a find and replace on the calls so that it uses snprintf or vsnprintf instead

No, it's not that easy.  Just look at the definition of `snprintf` or `vsnprintf` and you will see that they take an extra argument named `size` that specifies the length of the output buffer.  That's what the `n` in the function name means.  To make your code secure, you have to look at every place where you are doing sprintf, figure out the maximum number of bytes that it is safe to write into the output buffer, and pass that number as the `size` argument to `snprintf` or `vsnprintf`.

**Unsafe code:**

```
char buffer[10];
sprintf(buffer, "%d %d", x, y);  // UNSAFE if x and y can be large
```

**Equivalent safe code:**

```
char buffer[10];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d %d", x, y);
```

Maybe if all your code fits the above example, then you could do search and replace.  But for the cases that are more complicated you will probably have to think about it.

Comment: The search-and-replace will fail to do the right thing when `buffer` is a pointer rather than an array, but unless you're using buffers smaller than the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes), this will just cause your output to get excessively truncated rather than allowing overflows. And hopefully such truncation bugs will be immediately apparent as soon as you run tests.